# JSF 2.1 + CDI handling ActionEvent throws ViewExpiredException

Tags: jsf, cdi, viewexpiredexception

I'am trying to run simple example of my web app. I'am using JSF + CDI bean.

My facelet:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<h:html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head></h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:outputLabel value="#{testBEan.tekst}" />
    <h:form>
        <h:commandButton actionListener="#{testBEan.dodajCos}" value="guzik" />
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</h:html>
```

My CDI BEAN:

```
package pl.com.hrms.pages;

import javax.faces.bean.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named
@ApplicationScoped
public class TestBEan
{
    String tekst = "1";

    public String getTekst()
    {
    tekst = tekst+"2";
        return tekst;
    }

    public void setTekst(String tekst)
    {
        this.tekst = tekst;
    }

    public void dodajCos(ActionEvent e)
    {
    tekst = tekst+"p";
    }
}
```

When i run it web browser show the label with value "12" and button. If i press the button threse is an Exception throwing

```
19:05:05,903 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/H&RMSWeb].[Faces Servlet]] (http-0.0.0.0-0.0.0.0-8080-1) Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception: javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException: viewId:/pages/test.jsf - View /pages/test.jsf could not be restored.
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:205) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:116) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationPropagationFilter.doFilter(ConversationPropagationFilter.java:62) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
```

If i use @ManagedBean instead of of @Named it works fine (i mean pressing the button causes adding "p" to the label).

I have beans.xml file in a WEB-INF.

Does anyone have idea what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Please do not mix the `JSF Scope` and `CDI Scope`.

#### The JSF

```
import javax.faces.bean.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;

@ApplicationScoped
@ManagedBean
public class MyBean {
}
```

#### The CDI

```
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

@ApplicationScoped
@Named
public class MyBean {
}
```

I hope this may help.

Comment: I check it, but there is steel the same problem. What is weird, I copy exapmles from here: https://blogs.oracle.com/enterprisetechtips/entry/using_cdi_and_dependency_injection and i have the same problem.